# Max value in intervals in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, max, intervals

I have data with date time, height in power(10MB).
Example:

```
date<-c("9-1-2020","10-1-2020","11-12-2020","12-1-2020")
height<-c(32.2,32.3,48,35.2)
power<-(9,10,14,15)
data<-cbind(date, height, power)
```

I would like have intervals for height between 32 in 48 with step 0.3.
For each interval I would like calculate maximum value for power.

I have interval for height  example [30.2,30.4]. The maximum power for that interval is 10. In new data frame I would like save 30.3 for column height  and 10 for column power.

Comment: Not clear to me what you mean with 'max power'... can you post your desired output into your question?

Comment: Would you please explain more on your purpose? You would like to change the values of height column to intervals?

Comment: maximum value for data  power

Comment: what's your desired output? What's is the logic to reach your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
transform(
  out <- data.frame(height = seq(32, 48, 0.3)),
  power = data$power[order(data$height)][as.integer(cut(height, sort(c(30, data$height))))]
)
```

which gives

```
   height power
1    32.0     9
2    32.3    10
3    32.6    15
4    32.9    15
5    33.2    15
6    33.5    15
7    33.8    15
8    34.1    15
9    34.4    15
10   34.7    15
11   35.0    15
12   35.3    14
13   35.6    14
14   35.9    14
15   36.2    14
16   36.5    14
17   36.8    14
18   37.1    14
19   37.4    14
20   37.7    14
21   38.0    14
22   38.3    14
23   38.6    14
24   38.9    14
25   39.2    14
26   39.5    14
27   39.8    14
28   40.1    14
29   40.4    14
30   40.7    14
31   41.0    14
32   41.3    14
33   41.6    14
34   41.9    14
35   42.2    14
36   42.5    14
37   42.8    14
38   43.1    14
39   43.4    14
40   43.7    14
41   44.0    14
42   44.3    14
43   44.6    14
44   44.9    14
45   45.2    14
46   45.5    14
47   45.8    14
48   46.1    14
49   46.4    14
50   46.7    14
51   47.0    14
52   47.3    14
53   47.6    14
54   47.9    14
```